# Unable to read hidden field

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

In a partial page (a menu) I have this:

```
@foreach (var category in db.Query("SELECT categoryName FROM Category")) {
    <li><a href="#">@category.categoryName</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <form action="/Products/?@Request.QueryString" method="post">
                <input type="hidden">
                    @Html.Hidden("cat", category.categoryName)
                </input>
            </form>
        </ul>
    </li>
}
```

In the page I redirect to, I have this:

```
if (IsPost) {
    if (Request["cat"] != null) {
        <p>The category is @Request["cat"]!</p>
    }
}
```

It redirects fine, but I can't get it to pass the 'cat' variable to the page which I redirect to. Normally when I use redirect successfully I use input type="submit". The difference here is that these are hyperlinks, which is undoubtedly the reason. I would prefer to keep the hyperlinks.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to submit values in your form tag you have to submit the form. You don't have any code to submit the form.

Submitting the form is usually achieved by `input type="submit"` as you mentioned but other techniques are also possible (for example submitting the form with JavaScript).

In your case I wonder if you really have to perform a `POST`.

What about this approach instead?

```
@foreach (var category in db.Query("SELECT categoryName FROM Category")) {
    <li>
        <a href="/Products/?@Request.QueryString&cat=@category.categoryName">
            @category.categoryName
        </a>
    </li>
}
```